# Using POST in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, webserver

I'm having trouble in actually using POST to save/change information on my database. Could someone please help me?

```
NSDictionary *newDatasetInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:un, @"username", n, @"name", pn, @"phonenumber",em, @"email", nil];

NSError *error;

NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:newDatasetInfo options:kNilOptions error:&error];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

// print json:
NSLog(@"JSON summary: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

The code above is from the application my server side codes looks like :
Also please not that this code is in a php file

```
if(!isset($_GET["username"]))
{
    // adding new record
    $q = sprintf("insert into users (username, name, phoneNumber, email) values ('%s','%s', '%s', '%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["username"]),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["name"]),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["phone"]),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["email"]));
}
else
{
    // update the  record
    $q = sprintf("update users set name = '%s', phoneNumber = '%s', email = '%s' where username = '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["name"]),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["phoneNumber"]),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["email"]),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["username"]));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the most ideal way but I can present a working one;

On iOS side;

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:user 
                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                         error:&error];
    if (!jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
    }
    else {
        jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    NSString * params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"user=%@",jsonString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kLinkUpdateFacebook]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // and send the request
```

On php side;

```
<?
    $json_user = json_decode($_POST["user"],true);

    echo $json_user["name"];
?>
```

Comment: let me know if you need further question, this approach of sending it as a post parameter and gathering it in php as presented

Answer (score 0):

Have you decoded JSON Object in your PHP Code?

OR

Try setting as follows

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

And I am not sure if you need following

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but my php code seems to be adding a blank entry in to the database, it even does this when i call the url from my browser. am i passing in the information from the app wrong? or could there be a problem with my php file?

Comment: I believe that you need to access it correctly in the PHP. Because iPhone code seems correct.